# Consuming a Web Service from a Class Library

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Using Visual Studio I have a Class Library (C#) where I added a reference to a Service (more preciselly a Web Service).

The Web Service classes and interfaces where generated correctly, and I am trying to consume them using the following code (the web service receives an returns a string):

```
CallWS request = new CallWS();
request.input = "input string";    
WSClient client = new WSClient();            
CallWSResponse response = client.CallWS(request);
```

The last line originates the following exception:

**Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'WS_INTER' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.**

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you choose "Add Reference" or "Add Web Reference" when you were adding your reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an application configuration file and set up system.serviceModel section defining the address of a service.
You can certainly do that in code. Check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/82457a59-44f9-4efb-a814-0ed5a1ec0074) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103.aspx) for description

Comment: Thanks this is the correct answer.

Like I said I have 2 projects (Class Library and Web Application).

The web service configuration was on the configuration file of the class libary (app.config) but not in the Web Application.

Once I added the configuration on the Web Apllication, I was able to consume the Web Service.

Thanks